# How can I do smooth letter in text box(antialiasing)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, mfc

I have Text Control in our startpage. There is text in it. The problem is, that if we run the application , the text is sharp, not smooth.

For example, we create the font like this

```
CFont  m_secondCaptionFont;

m_secondCaptionFont.CreateFont(15, 0, GM_ADVANCED, 0, FW_EXTRABOLD, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLEARTYPE_QUALITY, FF_ROMAN, _T("Segoe UI"));


CBCGPStatic   m_labelProject;      // our static text control
m_labelProject.SetFont(&m_secondCaptionFont);
```

Is there any way to create smooth font ? Some kind of Antialiasing for fonts?

Comment: Have you tried the PROOF_QUALITY flag?  Also, why use GM_ADVANCED, when your escapement is zero?

Comment: PROOF_QUALITY does not help..

Comment: I use m_secondCaptionFont.CreateFont(50, 0, 0, 0, FW_EXTRABOLD, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, PROOF_QUALITY, FF_ROMAN, _T("Segoe UI"));    and it is ok, but for 50 still sharpeness is visible

Comment: Thanks, it was good way. I tried ANTIALIASED_QUALITY for bigger fonts.

Answer (score 3):

The nEscapement parameter specifies the angle in 0.1 degree units.  `GM_ADVANCED` is for use with a different API (specifically SetGraphicsMode).  It's value happens to be 2, so you've created a font that has a very, very slight slant to it.  This can defeat ClearType and other types of antialiasing.

Change that value to 0, and you should be all set.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but , I do not know exactly what do You mean, Where I should this value? Instead of GM_ADVANCED should be 0 right?

Comment: I used :m_secondCaptionFont.CreateFont(50, 0, 0, 0, FW_EXTRABOLD, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, PROOF_QUALITY, FF_ROMAN, _T("Segoe UI")); but for font 50 sharpeness is still visible. For 19 for example, it looks good

Comment: ANTIALIASED_QUALITY flag helps , for bigger fonts. Thank You

Comment: In your original post, you wrote: `m_secondCaptionFont.CreateFont(15, 0, GM_ADVANCED,  ...`.  That GM_ADVANCED does not belong there--it should be 0.  My answer explains how it could cause the normal antialiasing to be turned off.